# Given coordinates of two rectangles, find out if the rectangles overlap or not

Tags: objective-c, geometry

I'm having a problem with completing this code. I'm not sure how to implement 'struct' in here for the rectangle points `p1.x`, `p2.x` and `p1.y`, and `p2.y`. How would I continue to go about this problem?

Should I use CGPoint?

```
struct coordinates
{
    int x, y;
};

BOOL rectOverlap (int p1, int p2, int q1, int q2)
// getting error: "member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union"
// on the "if" statement.
{

    if (p1.x > q2.x || q2.x > p1.x || p1.y < q2.y || q2.y < p1.y) {        //this line error
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //nothing here yet.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objc there is a struct to define a rectangle called `CGRect`.
You can create one with the method [CGRectMake](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake)
Then you should use the method `CGRectIntersectsRect` which determines if two `CGRect` overlap or not. Its documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect)

Comment: I think you mean `CGRectIntersectsRect`. The `CGRectIntersection` function computes a new rectangle that is the intersection of its arguments.